# Coding Fogflow topology

Tags: fiware

I have just started developing a service on Fogflow and I have defined the topology by following the tutorial in https://fogflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example2.html. However, I would like to know if it would be possible to issue the topology by using code instead of the GUI to automatize the process. Is this possible?

Also, I couldn't find any tag for fogflow, could someone please create it? Something like fiware-fogflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have already documented the APIs of FogFlow Service Orchestrator. You can find the example of how to use its APIs to create and trigger a service topology. Please refer to the following link.

https://fogflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#apis-of-fogflow-service-orchestrator